# else-if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm facing a serious problem with else-if statements in javascript. i use them to assign a session variable to a certain value but whenever i try to do so it assigns it to the last value written in the last else if statements, the odd thing is that it goes into the right else if block and gets the value right then at the end of the function it changes it to a wrong value. 
Here's the code i'm working on:

```
function showInput(value){
   if(value==='username'){
       document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = "User name: " 
       <?php 
       $_SESSION['searchfield']="user name";
       ?>
   }
   elseif (value==='phonenumber'){
       document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = "Phone number: " 
       <?php 
       $_SESSION['searchfield']="phone number";
       ?>
   }
   elseif (value==='email'){
       document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = "E-mail: " 
       <?php 
       $_SESSION['searchfield']="email";
       ?>
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP = Server Side vs Javascript = Client Side

Both operate in different mediums on opposite sides of the HTTP fence

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server way before JavaScript runs. They do not interact. Learn the PHP lifecycle. When the Code runs on the server it will set all three of those session lines and it will always end up with email.

Comment: I love all of the other answers missed the real problem. Yes there is a typo with `else if`, but that is not the real problem! The real problem is not understanding how PHP/JavaScript interact.

Comment: oh, i'm new in using PHP. i didn't know this.

Comment: So you're saying that this can not be done this way ??? If so do you have any idea how to get it done ?

Comment: You need to make an Ajax call or submit a form to the server to set your session variable. Some sort of request needs to be sent to the server to update it. Without knowing the rest of the code it is impossible to give a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `elseif` in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Besides, what are you trying to do with mixing javascript and PHP? They're totally different runtimes. You need to do a **postback** to the server to store the session variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you indent your code properly?

elseif  is not proper javascript it's

```
else if
```

Comment: Fixing just the `else if` is not going to fix your problem.

Comment: I've just figured this out, so what will?